# Why does minerd.exe*32 process run in my windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, bitcoin

I have noticed now suddenly that a process called `minerd.exe*32` runs in my system along with process `update.exe*32`. These processes eat of a lot of CPU cycles. I googled **minerd.exe**. I came to know that it is a process used for bitcoins. But I am not using any bitcoins and I have never tried to access any bitcoin site from that machine.
Can anyone give more details as to what that process does? How it works? Is it a malware?

Comment: The process itself is not malicious but you do have malware that is starting it.  Most security software should find it.

Comment: You've been hit by a botcoin miner thief.

Comment: @FiascoLabs : I think you are right. They need machines that are on 24*7 and that machine is a server running JBOSS. So I was thinking How can I determine when and how it happened? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc

Answer (score 2):

Minerd.exe*32 is a process to mine bitcoins. Basically, the bitcoin network throws a *very* complex problem at all computers running this, and the first computer (or pool of computers) gets a reward.

Obviously solving a very difficult math problem takes a lot of processing power.

I recommend running [malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) and checking for viruses. Formatting your hard drive is the only *sure* way to be sure it's gone, however.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there a way of knowing how and when it got introduced into my system. The system it got introduced into is actually a server which is on 24*7. So, is there any kind of logs or anything to know when and how it go into that server.

Comment: Do a virus scan and find the file that did it. The look at the properties of the file. 99% of viruses are from skids from HackForums (yuck) with a free online crypter, just run malwarebytes and it should be removed.